# Atom Path Error. Can't Run Python Code

Tags: python, path, atom-editor

Whenever I try to run some code in Atom for Python I keep getting this error:

Unable to find command: python
Are you sure PATH is configured correctly?

I just downloaded Atom and Python 3.6.4 and followed some set-up videos for Atom, as well as reading through a bunch of forums with no solution, and I keep getting the error.

Comment: Well, what is the output of `echo $PATH`? and how did you installed python?

Comment: What is echo $PATH?

Comment: I first installed Anaconda Navigator, had Windows uninstall it. Then I installed Python off their website, installed Atom off their website, got the errors. I then went into my Local Drive and found that there were leftover files from Anaconda and the Python that came with it. I deleted all of that, uninstalled and then reinstalled Python for the 3rd time. Still got the same errors.

Comment: I thought you were under linux/unix based system ... So why don't you install it directly from https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/ ?

Comment: I figured it out. I had to uninstall and custom reinstall Atom, Python, and Anaconda Navigator a few times because Anaconda Navigator had been set as the default environment for Python on my computer.